# Always return a full object of specific GraphQL type

Tags: php, symfony, graphql

Is there a way to tell GraphQL to always return a full object of specific type?

If I ask GraphQL endpoint for something like this:

```
query {
  FooList {
    id
    price
    location
  }
}
```

I will get error `Field \"price\" of type \"Price\" must have a sub selection."`

The correct way is to ask instead

```
query {
  FooList {
    id
    price {
        amount
        currency
    }
    location {
        lat
        lng
    }
  }
}
```

It makes sense for most objects that you have to ask for details that you need,
but some like GPS coordinates, or price mentioned above will always return all fields 
(there is no point in getting just latitude)

Is it possible to mark a class in GraphQL schema to always return full object?

I am using overblog/GraphQLBundle as the server.

Comment: There is no syntax to support getting all fields -- you always have to explicitly request each field. This makes sense when you think about the fact that some fields might require subselections themselves, or might have required arguments.

Comment: Yest that is true for complex objects, but I am talking about simple structures like shown in my example. Think of them as multifield scalars.

Comment: Then you need a custom scalar